The process of doubling and removing zeroes and the number $234,715, 136$
Recently, i've been experimenting. What i would do is double the number, then remove the 0s in its digits, then repeat. There's lots and lots of cycles but i stumble a particularly long one.
$$118, 236, 472, 944, 1888, 3776, 7552, 1514,..., 2752, 554, 118$$
This is the largest cycle i can found, and it has period of $432$. The largest number in this cycle is $234,715,136$. I couldn't find any bigger cycle, and not for lack of trying. The best i could find is the cycle starting with 3714
$$3714, 7428, 14856, 29712, 59424, 118848, 237696, ..., 76776, 153552, 3714$$
This one has a period of $180$ and the biggest number in this cycle is $252,542,976$. Can anybody prove/disprove the claim that the cycle starting with $118$ is that largest cycle there is?

Please explain why the operation of "removing all zero digits" is of (mathematical) interest?

@BillDubuque   Just for recreational purposes only. I know that it is quite arbritary operation especially when done in base-10

https://oeis.org/A242350 says if you start with $1$ (instead of $118$) and follow the same rule then the "Sequence enters a loop having period $36$ at index $491$: $a(491) = a(527) = 366784$, min and max being $28714$ and $11772544$." So evidently someone has been interested in this sort of question before.

What happens if you start with $7$?

@GerryMyerson  It also ends with the cycle of period $432$. It is the same cycle as the one i found.

What happens if you start with $59$ or $295$ or $1475$ or $7375$ or $36875$ or $184375$ ?

@mathlove      I actually wrote a python program for applying this procedure to a bunch of numbers. But i couldn't find any larger cycle still.

How can the same sequence turn from a 36-period to a 432-period ?

@Bryle Morga : Did you try $59$ which is equal to $\frac{118}{2}$ ? Also, note that $295\times 2=590$ and $1475\times 2=2950$ and so on.

@mathlove      yes. In fact i tested all starting values from $1$ to $10^6$ and none of them produce larger cycles.

@Peter         Oh, it is a response to a different comment.Gerry asked what would happen if i start with 7

Do all the start values you examined eventually end in a cycle ?

@Peter         yes!!! And this should be expected because there's downside bias.

According to my program there is no further cycle with length more than $100$ upto $10^9$. In particular , the champion holds on.
